# PHP: copy MySQL database tables into new database table with additional columns

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

I am looking for a way to copy an existing database with multiple tables into a new database with the same tables and columns + some additional columns. So far so good. If I just copy the database to a new database with the same amount of tables and columns I am doing it like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| TABLE 1 |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Col1    | Col2    | Col3    |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

copy to:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| TABLE 2 |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Col1    | Col2    | Col3    |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Code:

```
public function loadDB($db1,$db2){
    $this->db->prepare("use ".$db1."");
    $sqlshow = "SHOW TABLES ";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sqlshow);
    $statement->execute();
    $tables = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    foreach($tables as $table){
        $sql[] = "INSERT INTO ".$db2.".".$table[0]." SELECT * FROM ".$db1.".".$table[0]."; ";
    }
    $sqlState = implode(' ', $sql);
    $insertStatement = $this->db->exec($sqlState);
    return $insertStatement?$insertStatement:false;
}
```

This code works and my database is copied successfully with all my tables and values inside my tables. What I need now is a working example of how am I able to copy the database to a new database where all tables have four additional columns like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| TABLE 1 |         |         |
+---------+---------+---------+
| Col1    | Col2    | Col3    |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

copying to:

```
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| TABLE 2 |         |         |           |           |           |           |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Col1    | Col2    | Col3    | Counter   | LoadDay   | User     | UserNew      |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | NEW VALUE | NEW VALUE | NEW VALUE | NEW VALUE |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | NEW VALUE | NEW VALUE | NEW VALUE | NEW VALUE |
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | NEW VALUE | NEW VALUE | NEW VALUE | NEW VALUE |
+---------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Code (what I´ve tried so far):

```
public function loadDB($db1,$db2,$condition){
    $this->db->prepare("use ".$db1."");
    $sqlshow = "SHOW TABLES ";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sqlshow);
    $statement->execute();
    $tables = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    foreach($tables as $table){
        $sqlshow2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table[0]." ";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sqlshow2);
        $statement->execute();
        $columns = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        foreach($columns as $column){
            $sql[] = "INSERT INTO ".$db2.".".$table[0]." SELECT ".$column[0]." FROM ".$db1.".".$table[0]."; ";
        }
        $sql[] .= "INSERT INTO ".$db2.".".$table[0]." (`Counter`, `LoadDay`, `User`, `UserNew`) VALUES ('1', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".$condition."', '".$condition."')";
    }
    $sqlState = implode(' ', $sql);
    var_dump($sqlState);
    $insertStatement = $this->db->exec($sqlState);
    return $insertStatement?$insertStatement:false;
}
```

The creation of the databases are working (not visible in my posted code here). I only get no values copied to my new tables inside my new database. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does NEW_VALUE mean in the last resultset ?

Comment: as you can see in my code below the table where you see the "NEW_VALUE", I add the same 4 new values to all new columns: 1, DATE, User Value and UserNew Value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final SQL query comes out wrong. I suggest changing your code to somthing like this:

```
foreach($tables as $table){
    $sqlshow2 = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table[0]." ";
    $statement = $this->db->prepare($sqlshow2);
    $statement->execute();
    $columns = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

    $sql[] = "INSERT INTO ".$db2.".".$table[0]." SELECT * , '1', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".$condition."', '".$condition."'" . " FROM ".$db1.".".$table[0]."; ";

}
```

Comment: thanks for your code. I tried your suggestion but it throws me a PHP error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in...! I am unable to find the typo. Any idea?

Comment: found the typo. Anyway your $columnsString does not seem to work. If I var_dmp($columnsString) I get: string(17) "Array,Array,Array"

Comment: I used select * instead if your columns in both tables have the same order it should work.

Comment: awesome...code is working now! Thank you very much. Will mark your answer as accepted answer.